# Level shifter for multiple voltage levels

Tags: i2c, level-shifting

I found basic level shifters for two different voltages but I have 3 different voltages on my I2C bus.

I just wanted to verify if the schematic below will work correctly. I think it will but I am not sure if the different levels will influence the working. 
[image]

Would appreciate a confirmation. (or if it does not work a tip how to solve this)

Comment: Not 100% sure if this will work or not, but if you consider the cost per location for pick & place, you might find it's actually more economical to just buy a one-chip translator or bus switch solution than to buy (and load) multiple FETs.

Comment: thx, do you have a suggestion for a specific component? And will this enable the use of different voltage levels on the bus?

Comment: I've never worked with I2C below 3.3 V, so I don't know off the top of my head which parts will work with 2.8 V. NXP and TI are two vendors that both have a wide selection of I2C translators and buffers that might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular circuit ONLY works if the signals are open-collector or open-drain, other wise you have this....

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCC0J6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Since you are using the circuit for I2C, that should not be an issue here provided the GPIOs are initially configured correctly at all three points.

Comment: Both the schematic and the first sentence of the question say "I2C".

Comment: @CL yes they do..but what is your point?

Comment: ow, indeed, I see. It is meant for an I2C bus. Arduino Mega is master and a BMP180 (barometric sensor) and aSIM800 (GSM IC) are slave... I guess it could have behavior like you drawn...??

Comment: The I²C specification says: "Both SDA and SCL are bidirectional lines, connected to a positive supply voltage via a current-source or pull-up resistor. […] The output stages of devices connected to the bus must have an open-drain or open-collector to perform the wired-AND function."

Comment: @CL yes I know, hence my edit, but still, you have to ensure the drivers are in that operating state.

Comment: Your first sentence still starts by saying the circuit only works for open-drain...which we know it is because it's an I2C bus.

Comment: @ThePhoton and it still "only works for open-drain!"

Comment: If someone asked "how do I fix my car", would you start your answer with "this only works if the vehicle you're fixing is a car..."?

Comment: Well you can't connect two push-pull outputs together and have them drive different levels. This applies regardless of level shifting! Or to continue the car analogy, it's like you said "Beware! This method ONLY works if you don't drive the car into a brick wall afterwards! If you fix your car using this method and then drive it into a brick wall you will severely damage it!" - crashing a car will damage it regardless of what method you used to replace the timing belt.

Comment: @ThePhoton yes, I guess the emphasis was in the wrong place. Still, it is worth pointing out the fact that it only works in open-drain for the next reader. I edited it accordingly. Answering the question title...

Comment: thx guys, looked up "open drain"... I get the point. learned something today... :-)

Answer (score 1):

It looks okay on paper:

- N-channel enhancement mode MOSFETs
- Drain connected to higher voltage side
- Gate threshold voltage low enough
- Appropriate pull-ups

The voltage domains are appropriately isolated so I wouldn't expect any compatibility issues.

Could be lots of other things that could cause problems in practice though, like gate capacitance, \$R_{ds}\$, switching speed, etc., so these sorts of things always need to be tested or heavily scrutinised.

Which is why I recommend using something off the shelf - there are lots of I2C level shifter ICs for just this purpose, and for a common use-case such as this you'll find it hard to do better with discretes.

Comment: thx, I guess the concept with 2 levels is heavilly tested: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12009. I used an bi-directional IC once (not sure which, I would have to look this up) but it heavilly oscilated. I switched to the mosfet concept and it worked flawlessly. The only thing I cannot assess (to be honoust due to my lack of electronics knowledge) is if it will work with 3 different levels.

Comment: Fair enough. Yep, it's fine - there's no way for the 2V8 domain to know about the presence of the 3V3 domain except by its effect on the 5V domain, which looks just like a 5V domain.